# How do you turn off right-to-left functionality in dealing with Arabic script on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try and highlight arabic text in VSCode it gets all janky trying to jump to right-to-left functionality. How do I completely disable all of this?

```
arabic,أخ,'ah+
arabic,أق,'ak+
arabic,أه,'ah
arabic,دا,daa
arabic,ذا,c+aa
arabic,يا,yaa
arabic,يح,yah+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83365) is a related GitHub issue. The short is that they don't support customizing any behavior around RTL scripts, and don't have any plan on addressing it any time soon.

I guess it's back to Sublime!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its scheduled for a fix in their backlog
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83365